# Data Validation with IF statement

Tags: validation, if-statement, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a data validation with multiple conditions. On this [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u3ZBcF119r6EEp7kGB8y9Jae8e5rpGO3-aP35wPKvdw/edit#gid=1649893968),

I have data validation on both column "J" and "K" Sheet1. The value of column K, will depend on the current value of column J. It does work on the first row, but on the succeeding rows, it does not, since my code for them still relies on the value of the first row, in this case, J4. Here's my code on sheet2(G1):

```
=if('1_Procurement Plan_Final'!J4="1.0 Goods",unique(B2:B),if('1_Procurement Plan_Final'!J4="2.0 Services",unique(C2:C),if('1_Procurement Plan_Final'!J4="3.0 Construction",unique(D2:D),if('1_Procurement Plan_Final'!J4="4.0 Lease and Rentals",unique(E2:E),if('1_Procurement Plan_Final'!J4="5.0 Others",unique(F2:F))))))
```

Please guide? Can I use array for this? Unfortunately I've been trying arrays but it always ends up in error.

Comment: @idfurw because the list for my data validation is on a different sheet?

Comment: Sorry, solved. I thought you are trying to set validation rule.

Comment: @idfurw how do you mean solved? Can you please guide?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `VLOOKUP`? Please provide and briefly explain your expected output.

Comment: @idfurw What I would like to achieve is, on column K, sheet1, I would like the list from my data validation on that column to match what ever is chosen on the data validation list on column J. Say for example, on J4, I've chosen "1.0 Goods", on K4, I would then like the list to be only related on "Goods". Same as on J5, J6, and so on.

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet publicly.

Comment: This is an extremely common question on Stack.  try searching for "dynamic dependent dropdowns" or "dynamic dependent data validation"

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot set the data validation rule to value in range dynamically.

The field only allows you to input a range reference but not formula.

Meaning that you may need to output each list, vary with the choice in column J, of column K somewhere else.

An alternative would be to use Google Apps Script.